# Highstock navigator add drag-end event

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to add a drag-end event on the navigator handles?  Because I would get the actually navigator selection from a chart

Answer (score 7):

Take a look on official [highstock demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/events-setextremes/). You need to hook a setExtremes event on xAxis, and check for `(event.trigger == 'navigator')`.

Hope this helps.