# How to get a summary from current navigator series of highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a highchart which shows tasks run during a period of time with a navigator. Is there a way to show a custom summary of all tasks showing number of success, failed or warning tasks along with the selected date range?

Note: As and when the navigator changes the summary is also updated. Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/grdAdW8AfFrRLYjLCCLh?p=preview)

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12666688/801116) that using setExtremes I can get navigator drop event but looks like I only get date and not other data fields.

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    tickInterval: 1 * 3600 * 1000,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        month: '%b %e, %Y'
    },
    events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {

            if (e.trigger == 'navigator') {
                $scope.taskstatus = e.min + " - " + e.max;
            }

        }
    }
},
```

Expected summary

[image]

**Update**

I am using highstock 2.0.4 version in this I cannot find currentTarget which is present in my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/grdAdW8AfFrRLYjLCCLh?p=preview)

for highstock 2.0.4 version below is the setExtremes function which sometimes gives incorrect counts, please help

```
$scope.setExtremesCall = function(e) {
    if (e.trigger == 'navigator') {
        var ftasks = 0,
            stasks = 0,
            wtasks = 0,
            alltasks = [];
        var currentSeriesArr = e.target.series;
        angular.forEach(currentSeriesArr, function(obj) {
            var currdatapoints = obj.segments;
            if (currdatapoints.length > 0) {
                angular.forEach(currdatapoints, function(inrobj) {
                    var firstKey = $scope.getFirstKey(inrobj),
                        taskStatus = $scope.getJobStatus(inrobj[firstKey].color);
                    if (taskStatus != null) {
                        if (taskStatus == "FAILED") {
                            ftasks++;
                        } else if (taskStatus == "SUCCESS") {
                            if (stasks == 4)
                                $scope.a = 1;
                            stasks++;
                        } else if (taskStatus == "WARNING") {
                            wtasks++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        taskstatus = e.min + " - " + e.max + " " + ftasks + " Failed, " + stasks + " Success, " + wtasks + " Warning";
        console.log(taskstatus);
    }
}

$scope.getFirstKey = function(data) {
    for (elem in data)
        return elem;
}

$scope.getJobStatus = function(stat) {
    if (stat == "#8CC051")
        return "SUCCESS";
    else if (stat == "#FF2A00")
        return "FAILED"
    else if (stat == "#FFCC4E")
        return "WARNING";
    return null;
}
```

Comment: yes you can get it done, it goes like this: in the setExtremes() event have a  callback function that will handle the data based on the min and max. from the event handler call this function with the min and max. in the handler run through your chart data and find out the valid/required value that fall in between the range. TADA!!! you got the solution

Comment: @strikers: I am trying to achieve this from navigator event. I have huge number of data so for every event if I iterate and check from whole series data, wouldn't it be a lot of processing, instead can't it be done from the navigator event's view of entire data series?

Comment: then there is a short cut. before sending the data to highcharts make a copy of it. make sure it is in a associate array so that when you get min and max you can simply cut that section from the array and use it for obtaining the desired output.

Comment: @strikers: Sorry I did not quite understand, do you have an example or can you demonstrate?

Comment: sorry i can't show you because i'm poorly acquainted with angularjs but I can guide you for sure

Comment: @strikers: no need for angularjs if you can use same data from my plunker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79005/discussion-between-strikers-and-abi1964).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a bit different approach. Check existing points (visible ones of course) and then divide that number by 2 (each line is built from two points). Something like this:

```
      afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
          var stat = {
             FAILED: 0,
             SUCCESS: 0,
             WARNING: 0
          },
          status;
          if (e.trigger == 'navigator') {
            var series = this.series;
            angular.forEach(series, function(serie, j) {
              angular.forEach(serie.points, function(p, i) {
                 if(p.isInside) {
                    status = $scope.getJobStatus(p.color);
                    stat[status] ++
                 }
              });
            });

            taskstatus = e.min +" - "+ e.max+" "+ Math.ceil(stat.FAILED / 2) + " Failed, "+ Math.ceil(stat.SUCCESS / 2) +" Success, "+ Math.ceil(stat.WARNING / 2)+" Warning";
            $('#summary').html(taskstatus);
          }
      }
```

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/btWjdME5UomLpsG6F1y5?p=preview

Comment: Good solution, but it might fail in a corner case, when there are 2 tasks which ended in current view but both tasks started at an earlier date which is outside the current navigator view

Comment: I modified the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9mZyemxcmSYFC03Xc134?p=preview) to demonstrate the issue. To reproduce this corner case try moving the end marker

Comment: Also is there a way to trigger this event so that after load completion of highchart the summary gets populated (without manually moving the navigator markers)?

Comment: To trigger use `chart.events.load` and there call the same method as for `afterSetExtremes`. Regarding issues, I would suggest first to organize your data (ascending order by x-values/timestamps) - it produces errors in the console. A bit different approach may be to use `series.segments` which should contain only existing shapes on the chart. Demo for both: http://plnkr.co/edit/eYgAmdgFOKQZQFKlas12?p=preview

Comment: I sorted my data to be in ascending order, but now if one slides (drag 1 day duration) the slider to the starting position of navigator I get `30 success` but when I count individual tasks, count is `18`. Please help. [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/v6KICJP0E4ABy2Mu5Vok?p=preview)

Comment: Interesting, sometimes points are rendered outside the actual range. In that case I would compare actual min and max with `point.x`: http://plnkr.co/edit/rXJPUoDOgkzCk7DmKLnJ?p=preview Let me know if something is missing/wrong.

Comment: To clarify: `segment[0]` -> starting point, `segment[1]` ending point (if exists). And compare: starting point > max -> don't count that point etc.